# H2o cross validation doesn't correspond to single fold train/test

Tags: python, machine-learning, random-forest, h2o

I'm trying to understand how does cross-valiation work in H2o when the folds are specified passing the  'fold_column' parameter. The library says:

> The fold_column option specifies the column in the dataset that
> contains the cross-validation fold index assignment per observation.

I suppose that for each cross-validation iteration, the rows with fold_column = i are used as the test set, and the remaining rows are used as train set. Though, if I instead train and test the model separately with the these splits, I get different performance results. In the example below I create a column with values between 1 and 5 to be used as split index, and use it to run H2o cross-validation (with fold_column parameter). After that, I use the same column to train and test a model with the same index and compare results.

Here's a reproducible example:

```
h2o.init()
from h2o.estimators import H2ORandomForestEstimator
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

# Import the prostate dataset
prostate = h2o.import_file("http://s3.amazonaws.com/h2o-public-test-data/smalldata/prostate/prostate.csv.zip")

# Set the predictor names and the response column name
response = "CAPSULE"
predictors = prostate.names[3:8]

# Convert the response column to a factor
prostate['CAPSULE'] = prostate['CAPSULE'].asfactor()

# Add column with random value between 1 and 5 to use for cross-validation
np.random.seed(21)
random_folds = np.random.randint(1, 6, len(prostate))
df_folds = pd.DataFrame(random_folds, columns=['folds'])
df_h20 = prostate.cbind(h2o.H2OFrame(df_folds))


##### Train the model using H2o cross-validation #####

# Train model using fold_column argument
drf = H2ORandomForestEstimator(fold_column = 'folds', max_depth=5, ntrees=1, seed=21)
drf.train(x=predictors, y=response, training_frame=df_h20)

# Get folds prediction single models
models = drf.cross_validation_models()

# Prin test and train AUC performance for each CV-fold
print('Fold 1, AUC (test) {} AUC (train) {}'.format(models[0].auc(valid=True), models[0].auc(train=True)))
print('Fold 2, AUC (test) {} AUC (train) {}'.format(models[1].auc(valid=True), models[1].auc(train=True)))
print('Fold 3, AUC (test) {} AUC (train) {}'.format(models[2].auc(valid=True), models[2].auc(train=True)))
print('Fold 4, AUC (test) {} AUC (train) {}'.format(models[3].auc(valid=True), models[3].auc(train=True)))
print('Fold 5, AUC (test) {} AUC (train) {}'.format(models[4].auc(valid=True), models[4].auc(train=True)))


##### Train the model on a single K-fold without using H2o cross-validation #####

# select one the of the 5 folds and create test/train set
test = df_h20[df_h20['folds'] == 1]
train = df_h20[df_h20['folds'] != 1]

# Train the model
drf = H2ORandomForestEstimator(max_depth=5, ntrees=1, seed=21)
drf.train(x=predictors,
                       y=response,
                       training_frame=train,
                       validation_frame=test
                 )


perf_valid = drf.model_performance(test)
perf_train = drf.model_performance(train)
print('AUC (test) {} AUC (train) {}'.format(perf_valid.auc(), perf_train.auc()))
```

The output is:

```
Fold 1, AUC (test) 0.8352221702976504 AUC (train) 0.835269468426379

Fold 2, AUC (test) 0.8215820406943912 AUC (train) 0.8203464750008381

Fold 3, AUC (test) 0.833563260744653 AUC (train) 0.8376839384943596

Fold 4, AUC (test) 0.8295902318635076 AUC (train) 0.8287798683714774

Fold 5, AUC (test) 0.825246953403821 AUC (train) 0.8264781593374212

AUC (test) 0.838142980551675 AUC (train) 0.8382107902781438
```

The results of the model trained and tested on a single fold without using H2o cross-validation does not correspond to any of the 5 results of the 5-fold cross validation, which is not what I expected it. I was actually expecting to see the latest results corresponding to one the 5 CV folds. As far as I understand, the H2o cross-validation should internally train the model in the same way I've done in the last part of my code.

Does anyone know why this happens?

**Edit:** I added the argument ntrees=1. I've done this to reduce the complexity of the model, making sure we're dealing with a single decision tree. I also added the argument seed=21 to both models.

Comment: `H2ORandomForestEstimator` (as all RF models) includes a random element, which makes the differences you observe not surprising at first instance. Try setting explicitly the `seed` in both model instances ([documentation](https://docs.h2o.ai/h2o/latest-stable/h2o-py/docs/modeling.html#h2o.estimators.random_forest.H2ORandomForestEstimator.seed)).

Comment: I added the seed and limited the number of trees to 1 in both models but the problem persists.

Answer (score 1):

There is no reason to expect that the AUC for any one of the folds should correspond to the AUC when trained on a single fold/the entire training data.

The AUC when trained on a single fold/the entire training data should correspond, approximately if not exactly, to the average of the AUCs for each of the folds.